# Convert a docx file to HTML without HTML, HEAD and BODY tags using PhpWord

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

Hi I am using PhpWord to convert a docx file to a html file. This works well however it contains HTML, HEAD and BODY tags, how do I convert a file without these tags, just the body content.

```
    $fileTmp =  public_path('test.docx');
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($fileTmp);
    $htmlWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML($phpWord);
    $content = $htmlWriter->getContent();
```

Comment: You're working with structured text; there's many ways to convert this text to an Object (or Array) and target only the properties you need. Have you tried anything? Where, specifically, are you stuck?

Comment: At the moment PhpWord parses the document well but includes HTML, HEAD and BODY tags and I was hoping there would be a method within PhpWord  that would exclude these tags rather than parsing the text again

Comment: You might be better to then use a DOM parser to extract the body content from the generated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use PHP's DOMDocument class to parse the HTML and then extract the body content.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML;

// Load the DOCX file
$fileTmp = public_path('test.docx');
$phpWord = IOFactory::load($fileTmp);

// Generate the HTML content
$htmlWriter = new HTML($phpWord);
$htmlContent = $htmlWriter->getContent();

// Parse the HTML content using DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlContent, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Get the body content without the HTML, HEAD, and BODY tags
$bodyContent = '';
$bodyNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
foreach ($bodyNodes as $node) {
    $bodyContent .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

// Save or use the $bodyContent as needed
echo $bodyContent;
```